# How to send JSON Data as response in Vue.js 2?

Tags: node.js, json, rest, vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing a website in Vue.js which uses a API (route -> `/api/**`), but I don't understand how to send JSON response.
Is there any method like `res.json()` express.js has in vue.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many times when building application for the web that you may want to consume and display data from an API. There are several ways to do so, but a very popular approach is to use axios, a promise-based HTTP client.

Basic example

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. In fact it deals with the opposite!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at "axios", a very popular and simple library for making HTTP requests - https://github.com/axios/axios. Read the documentation how to use it :)

Example of a GET request with axios:

```
import axios from 'axios'; // ES6

axios.get('/api/**')
  .then(response => console.log(response.data));
```